# Magento 2 - Category Save Event is not called when save category via rest api

Tags: magento2, event-observer, rest-api

I have created one observer **CategorySaveAfter.php** file in my custom module.

And calling this observer on **catalog_category_save_after** event define in **events.xml**

But somehow its not calling when i save category using restApi

Its working fine when i save category from magento2 backend it calling observer staightforward.

**But for Rest APi its not working** .

**Below code i have tried :**

**Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_save_after">
        <observer name="catalog_megamenu" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\CategorySaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/Observer/Categorysaveafter.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Categorysaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $test;

    public function __construct(\Vendor\Modulename\Model\ModelFactory $testMenu)
    {
        $this->test = $testMenu;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "goes here";exit;       
    }
}
```

**Yes i have added registration.php and module.xml file as well.**

**Update :**

Forgot to mention that i have tried global level **events.xml** as well . Like **etc/events.xml** and **etc/webapi_rest/events.xml** . **Still both way its not calling**

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you resolve this issue?

Comment: @LucaS yes i have override their existing model and its method and then save this

Comment: great, so could you close the question writing your answer?

Comment: @LucaS sure will do asap , Thanks for reminding me

Comment: Your class name is wrong it should be CategorySaveAfter not Categorysaveafter. as is used in the events.xml file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override core **CategoryRepository.php** file to changes your custom requirement.

**app/code/Package/Modulename/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository">
        <plugin name="CategoryRepositoryRestPim" type="Package\Modulename\Model\CategoryRepository" />
   </type>
</config>
```

Inside **app/code/Package/Modulename/Model/CategoryRepository.php,**

```
<?php    
namespace Package\Modulename\Model;

class CategoryRepository 
{

 public function afterSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $subject,$result)
    {
        var_dump($result->getData());
        $categoryId = $result->getId(); //get category id 
    }
}
```

Remove **var/generation** folder and check again.

Comment: Yes same way i have resolved this issue , Thanks for sharing the answer . Well explained :)

Comment: This answer not resolve why catalog_category_save_after event not trig from webapi_rest area...so is it a magento bug?

Comment: @LucaS yes might be it is bug , because we have tried to call that event from each area. likewise we have puted event.xml in globally , locally and webapi_rest folder as well still its not worked and then we have done another way

Comment: great, thx for your update :)

Comment: @Rakesh Jesadiya, code not working while saving category from backend magento 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

You should change your event area  for **global area** instead of ***adminhtml*** section.

Create **events.xml** at  `Vendor/Module/etc/` and then declare that event at  that file .Also remove `events.xml` from  `Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_save_after">
        <observer name="catalog_megamenu" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\CategorySaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that i have tried global level events.xml as well . Like etc/events.xml and etc/web_rest/events.xml . Still both way its not calling. Modify the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it not works from rest api call because you setted `events.xml` only for **adminhtml** area (see [magento areas](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/areas/areas.html)).

Try to define `events.xml` also in **webapi_rest** area or simply in `<module-root>/etc` directory as explained in [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html).

Comment: Forgot to mention that i have tried global level events.xml as well . Like etc/events.xml and etc/web_rest/events.xml . Still both way its not calling.  Modify the question as well.

Comment: Docs says that the folder must be /webapi_rest

Comment: Did it mean outside of the etc folder ? also provide me doc link for - webapi_rest if possible ?

Comment: No sorry, you wrote `etc/web_rest/events.xml` folder must be `etc/webapi_rest/events.xml`

Comment: sorry it was my typo mistake , yes it is in webapi_rest . But its still not calling

Comment: OK, so i think you have done all right. If with events.xml in global area it works for admin and not for rest api call, maybe your rest api call not fire the correct event. I haven't other hints.

Comment: Thanks @Luca S , concern here is event called on backend save click but event is not called on rest api . So something is missing or something is different for rest api

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer with Magento 2.3.4 and nothing was happening on that plugin so i searched the core Magento_Catalog Module and i reached the way to make the plugin work for me
this is based on @Rakesh Answer that helped me start, First

```
Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml
```

here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category">
        <plugin name="categoryRepositorySaveAfter" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SaveCategory" />
    </type>

</config>
```

then. the plugin class

```
<?php    
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class SaveCategory 
{

 public function afterSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $subject, $category)
    {
        $categoryId = $category->getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: @hitesh-balpande , i think this may help you with magento 2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

In case a plugin doens't work and you need to use an Observer:

The code in question with using observer will work if you change file name and class name from `Categorysaveafter` to `CategorySaveAfter` to match the capitalisation of the observer defined in events.xml.